# Remove "Delete" in node/edit via hook_form_alter

Tags: forms

I need to programmatically remove the Delete button in node edit forms under certain circumstances.

Normally, I'd do this in a hook_form_alter using `$form['actions']['delete']['#access'] = FALSE;`.

When I view in dpm(), "delete", however, does not have an "#access" key (though 'Submit' and 'Preview' do).  How do I disable 'Delete'

(…and, if you know *why* it wouldn't provide #access, I'm curious about that too).

Comment: I have checked `$form['actions']['delete']['#access'] = FALSE;` and its hide the delete button from node edit page. I also checked `print_r($form)` after `$form['actions']['delete']['#access'] = FALSE;` and `#access` was in `delete` button. Please check this again.

Comment: Yes, it does not exist in the array, and that line does not work. Perhaps my issues isn't standard and has something to do with a module I have installed, but I definitely don't have an "#access" for "Delete".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`hook_node_access`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7) instead

e.g:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_access().
 */
function MODULE_node_access($node, $op, $account) {

  if ($op == "delete") {
    // If no user object is supplied, the access check is for the current user.
    if (empty($account)) {
      $account = $GLOBALS['user'];
    }
    // You can add your own condition check here...
    return user_access("delete content", $account) ? NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW : NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
  }

  return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;

}
```

Comment: what is the value for `NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE` constant ?